# Join 2 table not displaying data

Tags: sql, join, phpmyadmin, concatenation, no-data

Currently trying to join 2 table (table process & table skill requirement)
But when using group_concat, it wont display if data in the group concat column (Skill Requirement) is empty.

It there any other way or sql line that i missed?

My expected result & current result is as below:

**Expected Result:**

| Product | Process | Skill Requirement |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 133 | Process1 | skill1, skill2, skill3 |
| 133 | Process2 | skill1, skill4 |
| 133 | Process3 | skill1, skill2 |
| 133 | Process4 |  |

**Current Result**

| Product | Process | Skill Requirement |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 133 | Process1 | skill1, skill2, skill3 |
| 133 | Process2 | skill1, skill4 |
| 133 | Process3 | skill1, skill2 |

This is my SQL :

```
SELECT process.product_id,
process.process_id,
skillrequirement.process_id, GROUP_CONCAT(skillrequirement.skill_req) as skill_req,
process.process
FROM process 
JOIN skillrequirement 
ON process.process_id = skillrequirement.process_id 
WHERE process.product_id ='133'
GROUP BY process.process
```

Update:

Sample input data
**Table 1 : Process**

| process_id | Process | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Process1 | 133 |
| 2 | Process2 | 133 |
| 3 | Process3 | 133 |
| 4 | Process4 | 133 |

**Table 2 : skill requirement**

| skillreq_id | process_id | skill_requirement |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | skill1 |
| 2 | 1 | skill2 |
| 3 | 2 | skill2 |
| 4 | 3 | skill3 |
| 5 | 1 | skill3 |
| 6 | 3 | skill2 |

Comment: It seems for me that you just need to replace "JOIN" with "LEFT JOIN", but to be sure, you need to show us the sample input data of both tables.

Comment: hi @JonasMetzler , i've updated my question with sample input both table. thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample data doesn't really match your expected outcome (for example, you are expecting a skill4 for process 2, but your sample data doesn't contain this). Furthermore, the query in your question is not valid and can't be executed. Anyway, as I already assumed in my comment, the main problem is that you need a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN` in order to also show processes without skills. This query produces the expected outcome if the sample data allows it:

```
SELECT p.product_id,
p.process,
GROUP_CONCAT(s.skill_req) AS skill_req
FROM process p
LEFT JOIN skillrequirement s -- Here you need the LEFT JOIN
ON p.process_id = s.process_id 
WHERE p.product_id = 133 -- Remove the WHERE clause if not required
GROUP BY p.process;
```

A note: I don't know if this is required for you, but if you want to make sure that the skills in the list are always sorted, you can add an `ORDER BY` clause to the `GROUP_CONCAT` part:

```
SELECT p.product_id,
p.process,
GROUP_CONCAT(s.skill_req ORDER BY s.skill_req) AS skill_req
FROM process p
LEFT JOIN skillrequirement s
ON p.process_id = s.process_id 
WHERE p.product_id = 133
GROUP BY p.process;
```

You can verify this here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TMGcqnkZ) and see the differences.

Comment: Yes you are right, the left join is what I needed. Thanks for the info. I learn something new today. :)